# How to check out a svn repo

Tags: linux, subversion

How do I check out a repo is stord in ./.myrepo?

[Here is the link to the complete task](https://piazza-resources.s3.amazonaws.com/j6zdjr2o14g248/j7hl17d3fku6te/lab1.pdf?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIEDNRLJ4AZKBW6HA&Expires=1505509798&Signature=TZcDZE8TUmA3jIFQAHegrm%2FYdKI%3D)

Not asking the entire thing just this part (I've done all the prior):

"2. Check out the svn repo stored in .myrepo to the directory 'myCode1'." (its in part 2 number 2)

I'm lost here. I'm extremely new to this could someone tell me what this means and how to do this? Thank you!

I believe I do `svn checkout` and the entire url in the current pwd? Aside from reading the definition on google I don't know what it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Name**

svn checkout (co) — Check out a working copy from a repository.

**Synopsis**

svn checkout URL[@REV]... [PATH]

**Description**

Check out a working copy from a repository. If PATH is omitted, the basename of the URL will be used as the destination. If multiple URLs are given, each will be checked out into a subdirectory of PATH, with the name of the subdirectory being the basename of the URL.

---

If you read this, it should become clear that `checkout` basically copies the repository into a folder. So what you will probably want to do is:

```
svn checkout file://./.myrepo myCode1
```